# Unresolved external when using boost log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm having problem while trying to use boost log. I'm getting following error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vms, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_log-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-1_60.lib
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound *)" (?release_compound@?$stream_provider@D@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@SAXPEAUstream_compound@12345@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound * __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record &)" (?allocate_compound@?$stream_provider@D@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@SAPEAUstream_compound@12345@AEAVrecord@345@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(class boost::exception &,class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name const &)" (?attach_attribute_name_info@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YAXAEAVexception@4@AEBVattribute_name@234@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::id<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::process> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::this_process::get_id(void)" (?get_id@this_process@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AV?$id@Uprocess@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@@2345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::unhandled_exception_count(void)" (?unhandled_exception_count@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YAIXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::default_attribute_names::process_id(void)" (?process_id@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::default_attribute_names::message(void)" (?message@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::default_attribute_names::thread_id(void)" (?thread_id@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::default_attribute_names::timestamp(void)" (?timestamp@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::default_attribute_names::line_id(void)" (?line_id@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::code_convert_impl(wchar_t const *,unsigned __int64,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::locale const &)" (?code_convert_impl@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YAXPEB_W_KAEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBVlocale@6@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::once_block_sentry::rollback(void)" (?rollback@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@AEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::once_block_sentry::enter_once_block(void)const " (?enter_once_block@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@AEBA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::once_block_sentry::commit(void)" (?commit@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock(void)" (?unlock@light_rw_mutex@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock(void)" (?lock@light_rw_mutex@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock_shared(void)" (?unlock_shared@light_rw_mutex@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex::lock_shared(void)" (?lock_shared@light_rw_mutex@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex::~light_rw_mutex(void)" (??1light_rw_mutex@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_rw_mutex::light_rw_mutex(void)" (??0light_rw_mutex@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::id<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::thread> const & __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::this_thread::get_id(void)" (?get_id@this_thread@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YAAEBV?$id@Uthread@aux@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@@2345@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_value_set::const_iterator __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_value_set::find(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name)const " (?find@attribute_value_set@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEBA?AVconst_iterator@1234@Vattribute_name@234@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_value_set::const_iterator __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_value_set::end(void)const " (?end@attribute_value_set@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEBA?AVconst_iterator@1234@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::construct(class boost::filesystem::path const &,int,unsigned __int64,class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::aux::light_function<bool __cdecl(void)> const &,bool)" (?construct@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@AEAAXAEBVpath@filesystem@5@H_KAEBV?$light_function@$$A6A_NXZ@aux@345@_N@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::flush(void)" (?flush@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record_view const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?consume@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXAEBVrecord_view@345@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::scan_for_files(enum boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::file::scan_method,bool)" (?scan_for_files@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA_KW4scan_method@file@2345@_N@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::set_file_collector(class boost::shared_ptr<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::file::collector> const &)" (?set_file_collector@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXAEBV?$shared_ptr@Ucollector@file@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@@5@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::text_file_backend::~text_file_backend(void)" (??1text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_set::~attribute_set(void)" (??1attribute_set@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_set::attribute_set(void)" (??0attribute_set@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record_view::public_data::destroy(struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record_view::public_data const *)" (?destroy@public_data@record_view@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@SAXPEBU12345@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute::impl::operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (??3impl@attribute@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@SAXPEAX_K@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void * __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2impl@attribute@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::push_record_move(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record &)" (?push_record_move@core@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@AEAAXAEAVrecord@234@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::record __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::open_record(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_set const &)" (?open_record@core@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA?AVrecord@234@AEBVattribute_set@234@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: struct std::pair<class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_set::iter<0>,bool> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::add_global_attribute(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute_name const &,class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attribute const &)" (?add_global_attribute@core@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAA?AU?$pair@V?$iter@$0A@@attribute_set@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@_N@std@@AEBVattribute_name@234@AEBVattribute@234@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::add_sink(class boost::shared_ptr<class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::sinks::sink> const &)" (?add_sink@core@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEAAXAEBV?$shared_ptr@Vsink@sinks@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@@4@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::get_logging_enabled(void)const " (?get_logging_enabled@core@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@QEBA_NXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::shared_ptr<class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::core::get(void)" (?get@core@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@SA?AV?$shared_ptr@Vcore@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@@4@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_formatter<char> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::parse_formatter<char>(char const *,char const *)" (??$parse_formatter@D@v2s_mt_nt5@log@boost@@YA?AV?$basic_formatter@D@012@PEBD0@Z)
1>a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 41 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm not really sure what is wrong. The libraries are there, the linker finds them. Just not symbols in them. Any tips?

Comment: treasure trove: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bboost-log%5d%20linker

Comment: Well, the unresolved external symbol is the symptom of the linker **not** finding them. What makes you think that it finds them?

Comment: If you are linking dynamically remember to define the macro `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [problems-linking-boost-log-1-60](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394896/problems-linking-boost-log-1-60-with-mingw-on-windows-7) WRT setting flags and issues when linking to boost-log on Windows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Problem was, that boost was compiled with _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 while I was building with 0x0501. Just changed mine to 0x0601 as well and it linked fine.

Comment: I had the same problem, but could not change `_WIN32_WINNT`. My solution was, to give Boos the correct version, using these defines:
`-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DBOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0501`

Answer (score 0):

But this program or application you created works in windows 7 or more. It does not supports for Windows XP.

If you want to create application that supports for windows XP, then you can use BOOST 1.58 version.
This version is last which supports from Windows XP. Then later versions supports more than windows XP (i.e.)From vista only.

Comment: That is not true. Boost releases up until 1.60 by default build for Windows XP. In 1.60 the default changed to Vista/Server 2008 but you can still build Boost for Windows XP. See here: http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_60_0.html

Comment: Okay Mr.Andrey. Thank you once again.