# Cannot understand what linker is complaining about

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, linker, boost-logging

When compiling my project that uses boost logging library, I am getting following linker error.

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sources::severity_logger_mt __cdecl
>   my_logger::construct_logger(void)"
>   (?construct_logger@my_logger@@SA?AV?$severity_logger_mt@W4severity_level@trivial@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@sources@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@XZ)

I don't know how to read this error message with mangled function names. Can anyone tell me in human readable way what function it cannot find?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: i have read the links provided and it does not help me at all as those answers are very generic. Please help me understand this specific scenario.

Comment: In short: have you been linking against the correct boost library (.lib) files?

Comment: Your linker is more informative than most. The first line tells you the linker is trying to find a symbol (something with a name, such as a function) needed in order for your program to run, but not finding it. The second line has unmangled information about that missing symbol - it is a function named `my_logger::construct_logger(void)` (the `void` means it is called with no arguments) and has a return type of  `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sources::severity_logger_mt`.   The `__cdecl` is compiler/system specific, but describes the calling convention of your function. The rest is the mangled name.

Comment: *"... it does not help me at all as those answers are very generic"* - Right. But the question lacks details like a typical compile command and the link command, so folks can't tell you much more. Why not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we get the details?

Answer (score 0):

Googling "boost log unresolved external symbol" leads to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html (first, highlighted hit) which describes `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK`.

This incidentally also the most frequent answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bboost-log%5d%20linker

However ABI issues can play a role, see e.g. [Unresolved external when using boost log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733872/unresolved-external-when-using-boost-log/34742561#34742561)